# Inner join returns single row instead of multiple

Tags: javascript, mysql, join

My inner join returns the first row only, but in my table has multiple rows. I had 3 tables. I'm performing join from main to secondary to the third one.

> Main (left join)-> secondary (inner join)-> third (return one row instead of multiple)

**First Table**

```
id name
1  john
2  abel
3  julia
```

**Second Table**

```
id first_table(FK)
1  1
2  2
```

**Third Table**

```
id second_table(FK) name
1  1                hello 
2  1                haha 
3  2                thanks
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM first_table 
LEFT JOIN second_table ON first_table.id = second_table.first_table
INNER JOIN third_table ON third_table.second_table = second_table.id
```

It returns first table and second table with a single row from third table

**What I want:**

Returns first table and second table with multiple rows from third table

Comment: `right outer join`?

Comment: is that a typo? LEFT JOIN first_table? could it be second_table?

Comment: Also, do you need to display all the rows from first_table regardless whether the id exists in second_table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
SELECT * FROM first_table 
LEFT JOIN 
(second_table 
INNER JOIN third_table ON third_table.second_table = second_table.id) 
ON first_table.id = second_table.first_table;
```

or similar result as your original query.

```
SELECT * FROM first_table 
INNER JOIN 
(second_table 
INNER JOIN third_table ON third_table.second_table = second_table.id) 
ON first_table.id = second_table.first_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is probably wrong. You are fetching from first_table and applying the LEFT join on first_table while the JOIN condition uses second_table.first_table column. That will throw an exception when executed. It should be like this and will give you multiple records what you desired. I have tested this on my end.

```
SELECT * FROM first_table 
LEFT JOIN second_table ON first_table.id = second_table.first_table
INNER JOIN third_table ON third_table.second_table = second_table.id
```

Comment: Sorry I had made a mistake on my query, it should be left join to second_table instead of first_table. Thanks for clarify.